# Linux Pseudo Terminal: function isatty returns true in child

Tags: c, linux, pty

I am trying to control tar via a pseudo terminal in a C program I have designed. The tar command I am using is: tar -cpzf -

What I am trying to do is to create a pseudo terminal, run tar with output directed to stdout. My plan was to read the data stream produced by tar in my C program.

The problem I am experiencing is that tar prints an error code and exits.

tar: "Refusing to write archive contents to terminal"

I looked in the latest tar source code and I see that it includes a terminal type check. Tar bails out if isatty returns true.

What control flag(s) must I set on the pseudo terminal to make function isatty return false in the child process?

Comment: Do not use a pseudoterminal; a pipe suffices here. Alternatively, pipe the output of tar through e.g. cat, as in `tar -cpzf - files-or-directories | cat`.

Comment: and why not use the available tools? `tar cpz file | myConsumingCprog` ? (My `tar` doesn't like leading `-` option specs (YRMV)). Good luck.

Comment: `isatty()` literally means **is** (this file descriptor) **a** **tty**. If the file descriptor actually *is* a tty (pseudo or otherwise), the function *shall* return 1. It would be a severe bug if you could somehow make it return 0 when the file descriptor was a tty. The curious thing is what do you mean by controlling `tar` via a pty? Poor old `tar` is the archetypal command line utility, it makes no use whatsoever of any terminal-specific functionality.

Comment: I already tried the pipe to cat, but I did this from a script. I do not think I can open a pipe directly when I spawn a child process? I think I had some problems with cat. I am sending the output from tar over the network, using my C program, from an embedded device. The device cannot store data thus your second suggestion will not work for me.